# wifi stops working after sometime while being connected in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I noticed this problem now while using live connections that my internet is fine wifi is connected but the internet is not working.

Here is the output of **lshw -C network**:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 30
       serial: 1c:1b:b5:ac:17:0a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-53-generic firmware=46.6bf1df06.0 ip=192.168.1.201 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a531c000-a531ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 0a
       serial: 54:48:10:e7:31:14
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8107e-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a5204000-a5204fff memory:a5200000-a5203fff
```

I've not changed any drivers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your issue is wifi, then the network card is the Intel and not the Realtek RTL810xE. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: It is clearly seen that my wifi card is realtek from the output of lshw -C network

Comment: "product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller" Ethernet is not wifi. Please check again. Your wifi is: "description: *Wireless* interface, product: Intel Corporation"

Comment: Oh yes sorry my bad it is intel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed because of autoselection.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Thnaks for your answer i will test the solution in 1/2 days. The connection from my mobile hotspot works fine(wpa2). I will also try to change my router settings because currently it is mixed-TKIP&AES. I think changing this may solve the problem. Thanks