# Unable to bring intel network interface up

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

Ubuntu server doesn't want to enable my wifi network interface: wlp0s12f0 on my laptop (Lenovo 300e 2nd gen): `State DOWN`

I tried ifup, iwconfig and ifconfig.
I wanted to connect my laptop to wifi, but It doesn't seem to work, also when I try to scan for ESSID's (wifi networks) there are no results, Im very new to linux and this is my biggest problem yet.

I have acces to the internet via ethernet, but I want to use wifi.
I also tried downloading the Intel drivers (Intel® Wireless-AC 9560) https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html
and followed the instructions in the README file, but it doesn't seem to work. maybe I installed the firmware incorrectly?

Btw rfkill shows that everything is unblocked, for either hard and soft block.

I can’t even bring the interface up. And when I scan for nearby networks with iwlist the result is: ‘’’ interface doesn’t support scanning’’’.
While I’ve used WiFi on that laptop before when I had windows on it (and it worked perfectly).

Any help would be appreciated! I'll try to follow the explanation as best as I can.

**RESULTS OF COMMANDS:**

results of `inxi -F`

```
System:    Host: tinisan Kernel: 5.4.0-92-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Console: tty 0 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: LENOVO product: 81M9 v: Lenovo 300e 2nd Gen 
           serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: SDK0K13476 WIN serial: <superuser/root required> 
           UEFI: LENOVO v: 9ZCN52WW date: 01/14/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT1 charge: 26.8 Wh condition: 38.8/42.0 Wh (92%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Celeron N4100 bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           Speed: 1274 MHz min/max: 800/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1359 2: 1492 3: 1115 
           4: 1437 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 605 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 99x31 
           Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console. Try -G --display 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-92-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp0s12f0 state: down mac: dc:fb:48:86:58:ee 
           Device-2: TP-Link USB 10/100/1000 LAN type: USB driver: r8152 
           IF: enx60a4b7714185 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: 60:a4:b7:71:41:85 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 119.24 GiB used: 8.32 GiB (7.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN520 SDAPMUW-128G-1101 
           size: 119.24 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 116.38 GiB used: 8.31 GiB (7.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 24.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 146 Uptime: 15m Memory: 3.65 GiB used: 349.3 MiB (9.3%) Init: systemd 
           runlevel: 5 Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

results of `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp`:

```
[    8.048173] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: loaded firmware version 46.4d093a30.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.108533] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9560, REV=0x318
[    8.163397] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: base HW address: dc:fb:48:86:58:ee
[    8.228987] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    8.354235] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0 wlp0s12f0: renamed from wlan0
```

results of `ls /etc/netplan`:
`00-installer-config-wifi.yaml  00-installer-config.yaml`

results of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  wifis: {}
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enx60a4b7714185:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

---

Sadly that did not work. Filled everything in, changed the name and password, but still state DOWN

```
2: wlp0s12f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:fb:48:86:58:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

resultst of `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` after applying newly generated netplan config.

```
[34755.190465] wlp0s12f0: authenticate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd
[34755.201294] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[34755.279308] wlp0s12f0: authenticated
[34755.284008] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[34755.385325] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 2/3)
[34755.388226] wlp0s12f0: RX AssocResp from b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[34755.391786] wlp0s12f0: associated
[34807.753881] wlp0s12f0: Connection to AP b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd lost
[38541.222178] wlp0s12f0: authenticate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd
[38541.233213] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[38541.275182] wlp0s12f0: authenticated
[38541.279868] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[38541.286145] wlp0s12f0: RX AssocResp from b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[38541.291834] wlp0s12f0: associated
[38543.403938] wlp0s12f0: Connection to AP b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd lost
[42456.806210] wlp0s12f0: authenticate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd
[42456.816128] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[42456.870032] wlp0s12f0: authenticated
[42456.873037] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[42456.879343] wlp0s12f0: RX AssocResp from b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=4)
[42456.884181] wlp0s12f0: associated
[42475.575404] wlp0s12f0: Connection to AP b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd lost
[44469.947395] wlp0s12f0: authenticate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd
[44469.956658] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[44469.999258] wlp0s12f0: authenticated
[44470.001978] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[44470.102939] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 2/3)
[44470.204198] wlp0s12f0: associate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 3/3)
[44470.345939] wlp0s12f0: association with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd timed out
[72354.380233] wlp0s12f0: authenticate with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd
[72354.390174] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 1/3)
[72354.529904] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 2/3)
[72354.728173] wlp0s12f0: send auth to b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd (try 3/3)
[72354.830578] wlp0s12f0: authentication with b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd timed out
```

Edit: Bump.

I think the problem has to do with  non-functioning drivers or firmware, But how do I know what software/firmware I need?
Again, Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Perfect so far. Now let's see: `ls /etc/netplan` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

Comment: After making the netplan changes, reboot and then show me: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you edit your netplan files:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml
```

Amend the file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp0s12f0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:    
        "********":
          password: "********"
```

Of course, susbsttute your exact details here.  Netplan is strict about indentation, spacing, etc., so proofread carefully twice.

Save (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor nano.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Your wireless should now be working, however, it might take a reboot.

Should you want a static IP address, please see the template:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml
```

I also suggest that you amend the other file to read:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enx60a4b7714185:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

I assume that, once the wireless is working, you will only rarely use the ethernet. Interfaces that are not required for booting or should not be waited on during boot should have the *optional: true* key added to them. This will prevent long delays in booting for interfaces that may not come up. (1)

Again, save, exit and:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

---

(1)  https://netplan.io/faq/

**EDIT**: We notice this repeatedly in your log:

> Connection to AP b4:fb:e4:78:75:cd lost

I suggest that you address the settings in the router using my suggestions here: [wifi stops working after sometime while being connected in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247887/wifi-stops-working-after-sometime-while-being-connected-in-ubuntu-18-04/1247931#1247931)