# Internet connection drops until I turn my laptop WiFi connection off and on

Tags: internet, dell

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 (but I have also had this problem with 18.04) on a Dell XPS laptop:

Very often, I seem to be disconnected from my home internet, as if the WiFi has dropped. But there is no problem with my WiFi and if I turn off the connection (on my laptop) and back on, the internet works fine again.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231281/wifi-connected-but-internet-drops-frequently) seems to have had a similar problem, but there is no clear answer.

---

Here is the output of `sudo dmesg | grep wlp0s2`:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sjDRHNVsnv/

Comment: It might help to look through logs on both your laptop and on the router to try to figure out why the connection was dropped.

Comment: Thank you. Do I need to run these logs when the WiFi has dropped?

Comment: You don't run logs, you look at them.  The logs are nearly always being recorded.

Comment: Okay so I can post these logs after the WiFi has dropped next time.

Comment: Yes, you can post them. Find out your interface with: `iwconfig` It will be wlx... or wlp... or wlo...something. Then check: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp3s0` or whatever you found. As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I will do that next time it drops. Thank you for the details directions!

Comment: Okay I have posted the output above in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your paste, we see that your wireless device is roaming, connecting, losing, reconnecting from as many as *six* wireless access points. I suspect that the first two are 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments of your own router.

We also see many repeats of this:

> Connection to AP xx:35:d1:28:33:xx lost

That suggests that either the channel or the encryption method has suddenly changed.

I highly recommend that you address the settings in your router: [wifi stops working after sometime while being connected in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247887/wifi-stops-working-after-sometime-while-being-connected-in-ubuntu-18-04/1247931#1247931)

I believe that your wireless device is very capable of connection to 5 gHz only.

Comment: I called my 2.4 and 5 GHz segments different names and now when I connect to the 2.4 GHz network it seems to be stable. Thank you!